# Celery using ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic, rabbitmq, celery, amqp, django-celery

Celery can currently work with RabbitMQ as a messaging system. I am wondering whether the upcoming release of ActiveMQ 5.8, [which apparently includes AMQP](http://activemq.apache.org/amqp.html) support, would allow Celery to work with ActiveMQ instead of RabbitMQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once Celery uses AMQP 1.0, then it should work.  Seems like Celery is still using an older version of the protocol so it's portability is going to be limited.

Comment: Thanks. But in essence AMQP support on both sides would imply compatible. Celery doesn't explicitly specify ActiveMQ and I couldn't find any info on this, so I though I'd ask...